# How to convert Multiple rows in a column for the same EMPLID INTO different columns ? Oracle or Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

In our table in Oracle SQL, we have a table where we are saving Students Courses Grades for every courses in different Terms.
Rows are repeating because of same Student ID (EMPLID) has so many courses and theri grades.
We need to convert courses into columns so that 1 student will have 1 single row.
How to convert via query in SQL for Oracle Or in Excel ?
Please answer

Table like this

[Actual Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc1Ih.png)

Desired Output:

[output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvdjB.png)

Comment: Dynamic columns are not possible without dynamic SQL

Comment: I think you should just select the data and create a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

For ***Excel*** solution you may try-

```
=LET(
x,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
y,TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B9)),
z,SUMIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,x,B2:B9,y),
HSTACK(VSTACK(A1,x),VSTACK(HSTACK("","COURSES",""),z))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Dear Harun24hr ,
But we need the name of courses as well in output table AA BB CC as columns.

Comment: @AhmedKhan this is the same formulas as given above Harun Dada, you need to tweak a little. `=LET(
x,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
y,TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B9)),
z,SUMIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,x,B2:B9,y),
VSTACK(HSTACK("","",B1,""),HSTACK(VSTACK(A1,x),VSTACK(y,z))))`